# Does the output from WEX support the entity type roles based on context from WKS?

Tags: watson-knowledge-studio, watson-explorer

If I prepare a machine learning model in Watson Knowledge Studio annotating using entities types with roles based on the context, will these entities types with roles appear in the reports and exported output from Watson Explorer (oneWEX) ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently entity roles will not be used as a facet when using your model created by WKS as annotator with other services like Watson Explorer generally.
Thank you.